# Angularjs route not work

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, express

I always get Cannot get /stock/new. Looks like I didn't set this route in express route. How angularjs's route working with express's route?

```
<a href="/stock/new">
    <i class="icon-text-width"></i>
    <span class="menu-text"> Add New Stock </span>
</a>

var aomaika = angular.module('aomaika', []);
```

app.js

```
aomaika.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/stock/new', { templateUrl: 'partials/new.html', controller: 'StockNewCtrl'})
    .when('/', { templateUrl: 'partials/index.html', controller: 'DashboardCtrl'})
    .otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
}]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the server side (as you said `express` side) I don't think you need any routes. AngularJS is purely running in client side. Assuming all your AngularJS files are stored under 'app' folder, then in server side you can host them with `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/app'));`, and that's all.

Answer (score 0):

The anchor should be

`<a href="#/stock/new">`